# How to read XML data and write to Excel sheet in Python for Selenium Automation

Tags: python, openpyxl, readxml

I have a scenario where I need to get the data from XML file and write the same to Excel sheet and use the same sheet for data processing.
I am able to read the data from XML, but not able to insert the same data (records) to an excel file
I am using OpenPyExcel for this, please suggest any alternative and help me here.
I am not seeing any error though, but nothing is being written to excel sheet

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import openpyexcel

tree = ET.parse("Test_Cust.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
workbook = openpyexcel.load_workbook("xml_excel.xlsx")
sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]

for items in root.iter():
    if items.tag == "Email":
        cust_email = items.text
    elif items.tag == "CompanyName":
        cust_cn = items.text
    elif items.tag == "FirstName":
        cust_fn = items.text
    elif items.tag == "LastName":
        cust_ln = items.text

        rownum = (sheet.max_row)
        print(rownum)
        colnum = (sheet.max_column)
        print(colnum)

        for r in range(2, rownum+1):
            for c in range(1, colnum+1):

                sheet.cell(row = r, column = c).value = cust_email
                sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = cust_email
                sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = cust_email
                sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = cust_email
                workbook.save("xml_excel.xlsx")
print("Done")
```

Comment: Why are you writing the same value to the same cell 4 times in your loop(s)? I'm assuming that has something to do with your issue.

Comment: Is your indentation different in your actual source?  As you have it above, none of your logic to write to the Excel sheet will happen unless `items.tag == "LastName"` is true, and then `cust_email` will only be set if an earlier iteration happened to set it.  If the indentation is wrong, please fix it. If the indentation is right, I could see that being your problem.

Comment: @JeffC, I am just writing the same value for testing purpose,

Comment: @CryptFool, I think the indentation is right, because with the same code (values), I was successfully able to insert the XML records to MySql database table

Comment: Hi, Somehow I am able to get some records into excel sheet. But all the time ONLY the last item of the XML file is getting written to ALL the cells of Excel Sheet

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing to the cell with this syntax?:

```
 ws.cell(column=colnum,
         row=rownum, value='mydata')
```

Note: you are saving the sheet in the inner loop. Slow!

Apart from that, this is a valid question: how can you easily read XML formatted data into OpenPYXL? But the question is more about parsing the incoming XML. That done, writing to OpenPYXL seems trivial.

(Oops, my mistake: my answer is for OpenPYXL, and may not work with openpyexcel)